TINA-TI 100 Hz Fully Differential Multiple Feedback Low Pass Filter Design Problem
I am trying to simulate a fully differential MFB filter with a cutoff frequency of 100 Hz in TINA-TI. I am using FilterPro for the filter design. In the image below you can see the design in FilterPro. When I pass the same design to TINA-TI and try to analyze the AC transfer characteristics, I get the output in the graph. What is the reason for the difference between the graph in FilterPro and the graph in TINA-TI?
I tried both shorted outputs and not shorted outputs below, however the graph is the same.




Why are you shorting the outputs?

@Andyaka I wanted to try it because it shows this in the schematic of the filter designed by filterpro, but I get the same result when I do not shorten it.
